# audio programming SDL - How to specify the cut of frequency in command line with wav file

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

Hi I am having a bit of trouble understanding cut of frequencies and how to add them to the command line what I would like to write in the command line is

sound.exe 230 dbz.wav
where 230 is the cut of frequency in 230 hz

i can load the wav file fine is just that i am lost as to how i should specify the cut of frequency this what i have written so far

```
if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s <input wav file>\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }
    if (argv[1] == "NULL") // NUll for now as dont know how to specify the cut of frequency{
        argv[1] = "dbz.wav";
    }
```

any and all help is truly appreciated

Comment: When learning to program, you'll need to learn how to break down a problem in independent smaller bits. How C++ parses a command line is unrelated to audio.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously the first bit is now incorrect as you want *two* arguments, `Usage %s <cut-off> <input wav file>`.

The second bit doesn't work. `argv[1]=="NULL"` is meaningless; it's always false. `argv[1]` is a pointer to the first argument, but `"NULL"` is a string literal in your executable. That string literal will convert to another pointer, and the two pointers will not be identical. Either use `std::string` (C++ style) or `strcmp` (C style, still possible in C++).

As for the new argument, that will be another string - after all, you don't control what the user can enter. He might type in "sound.exe 230Hz dbv.wav". You'll need to parse that argument. One easy way is `std::atoi(argv[1])` but that suffers slightly from a lack of error handling. `std::strtol` will return where parsing stopped, so if the user entered `230Hz` you'll see that parsing stopped at the `H`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a plenty of articles and libraries about command line parsing in C++ and I would suggest [AnyOption](https://github.com/hackorama/AnyOption) because it is compact, easy to use, and only relies on stl. For example:

```
void example( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    AnyOption *opt = new AnyOption();

    opt->addUsage( "Usage: " );
    opt->addUsage( " -n  --name         Wave file name " );
    opt->addUsage( " -f  --freq         Cut-off frequency " );

    opt->setOption("name", 'n');   
    opt->setOption("freq", 'f');

    opt->processCommandArgs( argc, argv );

    char* name = NULL;
    if( opt->getValue( "name" ) != NULL )
        name = opt->getValue("name");

    int freq = 0;
    if( opt->getValue( "freq" ) != NULL )
        freq = atoi(opt->getValue("freq"));

    delete opt;
}
```

For the audio part you need to be a bit more precise. What is your purpose? Do you want to apply a low-pass filter on the signal?